# Open a new Activity Xamarin restarts my application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Using Xamarin.Forms I have my main application running Forms. But I have Mapbox Navigation which is Xamarin.Android that I am using, I ma trying to open the navigation from Forms so I am doing the following:

FORMS CODE

```
 public interface INavigation
{
    void StartNativeIntentOrActivity();
}
```

The void above is then called through DependencyService in Forms

XAMARIN.ANDROID Code

```
 using Android.Content;
 using MapleLMCApp.Classes;
 using MapleLMCApp.Droid;
 using MapleLMCApp.Droid.NavigationUI;
 using System;
 using Xamarin.Forms;

 [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NavInitializer))]
 namespace MapleLMCApp.Droid
 {   
     class NavInitializer : INavigation
     {    
         public void StartNativeIntentOrActivity()
         {
             //Begin Navigation Form
             try
             {
                 var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(EmbeddedNavigationActivity));
                 intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);   
                 Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);           
            
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 LogFileCreation lg = new LogFileCreation();
                 lg.CreateLog(ex.ToString(), "NAV Initilizer Error");
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

The above works perfectly in the emulator for API <28 and API >28

The second I try the code above on my Huawei P30 Pro the second the new activity appears the App restarts itself or auto closes...

Any ideas on what might be causing this? some security setting or Manifest property that needs to be set or something along those lines?

Comment: Can you please try `Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);` as mentioned in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/163239/is-it-possible-to-startactivity-from-xamarin-forms-shared).

Comment: Thanks for the response, it lead me to try a different route of debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fetchRoute() event that starts as the new activity opens. This has an error on the P30 Pro due to culture variants on double parse...It was attempting to parse 27,33 as a double and needed to be 27.33

The form now opens without any issues

Comment: Can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).